# Grouping objects based on overlapping time interval

Tags: java, list, grouping

I have a class,

```
class A{
    ...
    private Interval interval;
    ...
}

//maintaining epoch time
class Interval{
    private long left;
    private long right;

    public Interval(long left, long right){
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }
//getters and setters
}
```

I have a list of objects `List<A>` and I want to group the objects which have overlapping(transitive overlapping, i.e. `a = b, b = c then a = c`) intervals. Lets suppose I have 4 objects,

```
A1 - Interval - 09:00 to 10:00
A2 - Interval - 13:00 to 14:00
A3 - Interval - 10:10 to 12:00
A4 - Interval - 09:30 to 10:30
```

The result of the program should give me 2 lists,

```
List1 - A1,A3,A4
List2 - A2
```

Any suggestions on solving this issue and/or pseudo-code?

Comment: You probably want to check out [interval trees](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree)

Comment: How many intervals will you be handling at a time? I can suggest a simple solution that I think should be O(n^2) in the number of intervals, which wouldn't be too bad if you aren't handling a lot of them in a group.

Comment: Will be handling fewer than 1000 objects.

Comment: If you can, maintain the data in groups as they are added, it'll solve the issue with having to process each element in the list

Comment: @MadProgrammer: That actually brings up a good point. I think the solution I'm working on is actually n*log(n) in # of intervals, but it assumes you start with the number of intervals, and then merge them all into groups. It's not "online" in that it doesn't naturally handle new additions of intervals without re-processing. Although it could easily be adapted to be online since it relies on sorting the intervals by starting point. You could use a binary tree (or similar) to do online sorting, and then process the merge in O(n) when you needed it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the verbosity, but I believe the question merits it :-) . This solution is **n*log(n)** in the number of intervals. The location where this complexity occurs is within the sorting of the intervals. Note that this solution takes care to include cases where one interval is contained completely inside another. The result groups have their sub-intervals reverse ordered, but you can easily fix this if you like by reversing the list at the end. I wouldn't recommend fixing it by inserting the joined intervals at the beginning rather than the end as this increases complexity to O(n^2) if you are using an ArrayList based implementation. I suppose you could probably use a LinkedList and insert at the beginning, but that might hurt you in other places, depending on what you do with these groups after you've formed them.

```
public static long max(long a, long b){
    return (a>b ? a : b);
}

public static long min(long a, long b){
    return (a<b ? a : b);
}

/**
 * A meta interval is composed of sub intervals. Its left endpoint is
 * the leftmost point of its subintervals and its right endpoint is 
 * the rightmost point of its subintervals. 
 */
static class MetaInterval extends Interval{

    /**
     * meta intervals are composed of lists of subintervals.
     */
    private List<Interval> subintervals;

    public MetaInterval(Interval initialSubInterval){
        super(initialSubInterval.getLeft(),initialSubInterval.getRight(),null);
        this.subintervals = new ArrayList<Interval>();
        this.subintervals.add(initialSubInterval);
    }

    public void join(MetaInterval other){
        verifyOverlap(other);

        this.setLeft(min(this.getLeft(),other.getLeft()));
        this.setRight(max(this.getRight(),other.getRight()));
        this.subintervals.addAll(other.getSubintervals());

        other.invalidate();
    }

    public void setSubintervals(List<Interval> subintervals){
        this.subintervals = subintervals;
    }

    public List<Interval> getSubintervals(){
        return this.subintervals;
    }

    private void invalidate(){
        this.setSubintervals(null);
        this.setLeft(0);
        this.setRight(0);
    }

    public boolean isInvalid(){
        return this.getSubintervals()==null;
    }


}

//maintaining epoch time
static class Interval implements Comparable<Interval>{
    private long left;
    private long right;

    private String intervalId;

    public Interval(long left, long right, String intervalId){
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
        this.intervalId = intervalId;
    }

    public boolean pointIsIn(long point){
        return (point>=this.getLeft() && point<=this.getRight());
    }

    public long getLeft(){
        return left;
    }

    public long getRight(){
        return right;
    }

    public void setLeft(long left){
        this.left = left;
    }

    public void setRight(long right){
        this.right = right;
    }

    public String getIntervalId(){
        return intervalId;
    }

    public boolean overlaps(Interval other){
        return pointIsIn(other.getLeft()) || pointIsIn(other.getRight()) || other.pointIsIn(getLeft()) || other.pointIsIn(getRight());
    }

    public void verifyOverlap(Interval other){
        if(!overlaps(other)){
            throw new IllegalStateException("Other interval does not overlap");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sort by leftmost part of interval.
     */
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Interval o) {
        return Long.compare(this.getLeft(), o.getLeft());
    }

    public String toString(){
        return intervalId+":["+getLeft()+","+getRight()+"]";
    }
}

/**
 * Given a list of intervals, returns a list of interval groups where
 * the intervals in the groups all overlap. So if A overlaps with B and
 * B with C, then A,B,and C will be returned in a group. Supposing intervals
 * D  and E share nothing with A, B, or C, but do share with each other, D and E
 * will be returned as a separate group from A,B,C.
 * @param baseIntervals
 * @return
 */
public static List<List<Interval>> getOverlappingGroups(List<Interval> baseIntervals){
    List<MetaInterval> baseMetaIntervals = toMetaIntervals(baseIntervals);

    List<MetaInterval> mergedMetaIntervals = getMergedMetaIntervals(baseMetaIntervals);

    List<List<Interval>> intervalGroups = metaIntervalsToGroups(mergedMetaIntervals);
    return intervalGroups;
}



private static List<MetaInterval> getMergedMetaIntervals(
        List<MetaInterval> metaIntervals) {
    if(metaIntervals.isEmpty()){
        return metaIntervals;
    }
    //order the meta intervals by their starting point.
    Collections.sort(metaIntervals);

    //go through and merge the overlapping meta intervals.
    //This relies on the logic that if interval i overlaps with
    //an interval that started before it, then once all the intervals
    //before i have been merged, interval i will have a starting point
    //consecutive to the starting point of the the preceeding interval.
    for(int i=0; i< metaIntervals.size()-1; i++){
        MetaInterval thisInterval = metaIntervals.get(i);
        MetaInterval nextInterval = metaIntervals.get(i+1);

        if(thisInterval.overlaps(nextInterval)){
            nextInterval.join(thisInterval);
        }
    }

    List<MetaInterval> resultIntervals = new ArrayList<MetaInterval>();

    //All intervals from the original list either:
    //(a) didn't overlap with any others
    //(b) overlapped with others and were chosen to represent the merged group or
    //(c) overlapped with others, were represented in the group in another meta 
    // interval, and then marked as invalid.
    //Go through and only add the valid intervals to be returned.

    for(MetaInterval i : metaIntervals){
        if(!i.isInvalid()){
            resultIntervals.add(i);
        }
    }
    return resultIntervals;
}

/**
 * Convert a list of meta intervals into groups of intervals.
 * @param mergedMetaIntervals
 * @return
 */
private static List<List<Interval>> metaIntervalsToGroups(
        List<MetaInterval> mergedMetaIntervals) {
    List<List<Interval>> groups = new ArrayList<>(mergedMetaIntervals.size());
    for(MetaInterval metaInterval : mergedMetaIntervals){
        groups.add(metaInterval.getSubintervals());
    }
    return groups;
}

private static List<MetaInterval> toMetaIntervals(
        List<Interval> baseIntervals) {
    ArrayList<MetaInterval> metaIntervals = new ArrayList<MetaInterval>(baseIntervals.size());
    for(Interval i : baseIntervals){
        metaIntervals.add(new MetaInterval(i));
    }

    return metaIntervals;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Interval a = new Interval(20, 30, "A");
    Interval b = new Interval(21,22,"B");
    Interval c = new Interval(500,503,"C");
    Interval d = new Interval(28,38, "D");
    Interval e = new Interval(490,502,"E");



    //note: A,B, and D are an overlapping group, and
    //D and E are another.
    List<List<Interval>> intervalGroups = getOverlappingGroups(Arrays.asList(a,b,c,d,e));

    for(List<Interval> group : intervalGroups){
        System.out.println(group.toString());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[D:[28,38], B:[21,22], A:[20,30]]
[C:[500,503], E:[490,502]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the `Interval` class (I didn't make getters/setters - I'm lazy like that):

```
class Interval {
    public long left;
    public long right;
    public String name;
    public Interval(String name, long left, long right) {
        this.name = name;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }
    public boolean overlaps(Interval other) {
        return (this.left >= other.left && this.left <= other.right)
                || (this.right <= other.right && this.right >= other.left)
                || (other.left >= this.left && other.left <= this.right)
                || (other.right <= this.right && other.right >= this.left);
    }
}
```

Now we can run this program:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Interval> all = new ArrayList<Interval>();
        all.add(new Interval("A",0,10));
        all.add(new Interval("B",30,40));
        all.add(new Interval("C",5,15));
        all.add(new Interval("D",15,30));

        // We run our algorithm...
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Interval>> result = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Interval>>();
        for (Interval interval : all) {
            if (result.isEmpty()) {
                result.add(new ArrayList<Interval>());
                result.get(0).add(interval);
            }else{
                boolean addedSomewhere = false;
                for (ArrayList<Interval> group : result) {
                    for (Interval other : group) {
                        if (other.overlaps(interval)) {
                            group.add(interval);
                            addedSomewhere = true;
                        }
                        if (addedSomewhere) break;
                    }
                    if (addedSomewhere) break;
                }
                if (!addedSomewhere) {
                    result.add(new ArrayList<Interval>());
                    result.get(result.size() - 1).add(interval);
                }
            }
        }

        // Print the result...
        for (ArrayList<Interval> group : result) {
            System.out.print("{");
            for (Interval interval : group) {
                System.out.print("[" + interval.name + "," + interval.left + "," + interval.right + "]");
            }
            System.out.print("}\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Which outputs this:

```
{[A,0,10][C,5,15][D,15,30]} 
{[B,30,40]}
```

Comment: Your overlaps method doesn't take into account the case where `this` interval completely encloses the other.

Comment: This looks O(n^2), maybe O(n^3). It would be n^2 if everything overlapped or if nothing overlapped. Haven't thought too hard about intermediate cases.

Comment: K, thinking about it some more it doesn't get worse than n^2. You still haven't fixed the issue of overlap not considering completely contained intervals though. Try your algorithm on these inputs: `Interval a = new Interval("A",20, 30);
  Interval b = new Interval("B",21,22);
  Interval c = new Interval("C",500,503);
  Interval d = new Interval("D",28,38);
  Interval e = new Interval("E",490,502);`